# writing a scheduler and backend in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I am trying to write a very simple rails backend backed up with a mysql database. It's very simple, I have two tables, one is the users table, tweets table, and a time for each tweet. Basically besides just an API, I would like to write a scheduler for posting the tweets at a specific time in the database. This is what confuses me.. how do I write a loop in the background that always checks the current time if there's any tweet that needs to be posted?

Any recommendation/guidelines in achieving this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a background job management.

Periodically, you will check if there is anything to do and eventually do it.

Please check [this relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977735/whats-the-best-background-job-management-library-for-rails).

Here are some other pointers:

- http://4loc.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/background-jobs-in-ruby-on-rails/
- https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job
- https://github.com/javan/whenever/

Comment: if I were to use delayed job then I don't even need a database to store the tweets... I assume, as I can just set delayed_jobs to execute at a certain time?

Comment: You will probably still need to use the database if you need to retain the tweet before the actual posting. If you have a tweet now that you want to post tomorrow, save it now in the database and let the delayed job fetch it and post it tomorrow.